# Optimal way to suggest random available username like gmail using Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Was just wondering, what would be the ideal way to suggest random available username after user keyed-in username is not available.

When user keys-in for a particular username, my application would check the same in database (am using PostgreSQL and Django) and returns error. Then i would like to suggest few available usernames. At this point, i shall have following data:

```
User FirstName (optional)
User LastName (optional)
User keyed-in desired username (Which is not available)
User email-id or social username
Might have someother info like address.
```

Now, i can easily generate some random-id based on above available variables, but is it like everytime i need to check the output with DB right? what would be the ideal way to do this? For example, for two users, who have their FN,LN same i shouldn't end up suggesting same set of usernames!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you only need to generate this suggested user name list very infrequently (once per attempt that results in a collision), you could very easily check the generated suggested values against the database and exclude from the result those that already exist.

Alternatively, since I'm guessing your site isn't going to have millions of users, you could forego making this check at all since the likelihood of username collisions on a small set of users is very low, and the results of a collision are annoying, but not fatal to the user experience.

Comment: Thanks Colin! 
Actually, its not login - usernames, some other unique-ids tagged to user, a user can have multiple id's like this, which is a special feature on the app.